# Как удалить найденные endswith элементы?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Согласно примеру должны были удалиться 11 и 211 элементы списка:

```
a = [1, 11, 21, 31, 211, 221]
s=len(a)

s=len(a)
for i in range(s):
    if str(a[i]).endswith('11'):
        # print(a[i])  - чтобы показать, что элементы есть в списке 
        a.remove(a[i])
print(a)
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Ну чисто так... у тебя 6 элементов... ты в цикле удалил, скажем, 2-й, осталось 5 элементов... что будет, когда счётчик цикла доберётся до 6?

Comment: Количество элементов уменьшится на один, следовательно индекс позиции изменится. Значит мне нужно каким-то образом уменьшать диапазон на еденицу. Надо подумать как сделать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что при прохождении по элементам коллекции от начала до конца, был уменьшен размер коллекции, поэтому в какой-то момент один из индексов вышел за пределы коллекции.

Чтобы это обойти, нужно делать обход в обратном порядке:

```
a = [1, 11, 21, 31, 211, 221]

for i in reversed(range(len(a))):
    if str(a[i]).endswith('11'):
        a.remove(a[i])

print(a)
# [1, 21, 31, 221]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Юра, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать фильтры.

```
a = [1, 11, 21, 31, 211, 221]
a = filter( lambda x: not str(x).endswith('11'), a )
print(list(a))
```

Comment: Нужно еще привести это к списку

Comment: как подметил gil9red нужно привести к списку, исправил ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное!  Разобрался.